# How to print one column to other columns combined path without awk?

Tags: text-processing

I want to realize the same function as the `awk` command:

```
awk  -F ";" '{print $3 >  "/" $1 "/" $2}' file
```

For example:

I have a file with two lines as input:

```
path1;filename_1;f3_1
path2;filename_2;f3_2
```

I want the output as:

- in the file `/path1/filename_1`, the content is `f3_1`
- in the file `/path2/filename_2`, the content is `f3_2`

When I do that with awk, I got the 141 exit code, SIGPIPE. I just want to bypass this error.

Comment: What's wrong with using `awk` for this?  Is there a specific tool/language you want to use instead?

Comment: @Mike see my updated answer. At first I misread the question.

Comment: When I do that with awk, I got the 141 exit code, SIGPIPE. I just want to bypasee this error...

Comment: @JigglyNaga For more information, I got 141 when the file to treat is huge 4Go. When I use the same awk command to treat small file. There is no problem.

Comment: Where's the pipe (or socket)? You get a SIGPIPE when you write to a closed pipe of socket. Are any of those /path/filename pipes?

Comment: How about adding another print before the existing print, so that you can see how far it progressed in the file before failing? This may give you an indication of which file causes the trouble.

Comment: The command I used is just as I put at the begin. In this command, there is no pipe. But I think awk will use pipe to realize this fonction. The  awk command failed immediatelly just after launch it. So I don't think it's the problem during the file treating. This awk command works well for small file. Just for a huge file, it doesn't work. And in an other environnement, we do the test with the same huge file and the same awk command. It works... The two environnements are two different vm but based on the same physical server. We have started to check the configurations of the two env.

Comment: Question: are the files distinct? Because if your `awk` program has two or more lines like `same;file;content1`, `same;file;content2` etc., The file will actually contain two lines, `content1` and `content2`. `awk` has to keep the file opened throughout the program, so of course for a huge file it may run out of pipelines.

Comment: Neither `gawk` nor `mawk` nor busybox `awk` nor opensolaris `awk` use pipes or sockets. What system is it? What `awk` implementation and version?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, it may run out of _file descriptors_, but GNU `awk` at least knows how to work around that (it closes fds and reopens them later with O_APPEND if need be when it runs out of fds).

Comment: I will update when I have the information of system. But I want to say that the awk fails just after launching it. Your explications should happen during the file treatement, not at the very beginning. Isn't it? @RealSkeptic the files are not distinct.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It depends on the underlying system, and we don't know that the awk in question is actually gawk. It could be mawk or some other implementation.

Comment: system information where the awk works:

`uname -a
Linux zed335a0 2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 26 13:37:13 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`awk -W version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2009 Free Software Foundation.`

Comment: Can you run `strace awk  -F ";" '{print $3 >  "/" $1 "/" $2}' file` (if on Linux) to see what causes the SIGPIPE?

Comment: What do you see if you run `(trap '' PIPE; awk  -F ";" '{print $3 >  "/" $1 "/" $2}' file)`?

Comment: I don't have access to the environnement where awk doesn't work. désolé

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas I have updated in the last answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `awk` is running out of file-handles.  The obvious solution, if you can't upgrade to a newer version of `awk`, is to close the files after we use them.

Are any of the  `path;filename` combinations likely to appear more than once?

If not, try:

```
awk  -F ";" '{f="/"$1"/"$2; print $3 > f ; close(f)}' file
```

Otherwise, use `>> f` if appending to an existing file is OK:

```
awk  -F ";" '{f="/"$1"/"$2; print $3 >> f ; close(f)}' file
```

If the file needs to be truncated the first time it is written to but appended from then on, it's slightly more complicated:

```
awk  -F ";" '{ f="/"$1"/"$2;
               if ( !fnames[f]++ ) { print > f };
               print $3 >> f;
               close(f)
             }' file
```

The `fnames` associative array is used to determine whether the script has seen this filename yet or not.  if not, it truncates the file.

Comment: Your solution works. There is no 141 any more. Finally, we use this adapted code                                                                                         `awk -v CHEMIN="${PATH_EXP_PREPARATION}" -F"${SEPARATEUR_FICHIER_SOURCE}" '{ f=CHEMIN "/" $1 "/" $2; if ( NR == 1 ) prvf=f; print $3 > f ; if ( f != prvf ) {close(prvf); prvf=f; }}' ${FICHIER_SOURCE}`

Comment: @Mike Note that upon running out of fds, the `open()` witll fail with EMFILE, you would not get a SIGPIPE. GNU `awk` works around (and has been for decades) the problem by --upon EMFILE-- closing an earlier open fd and try again (and if the closed file is referenced again later, it is open with O_APPEND). So I'd bet it's not gawk you use on that system. It'd be interesting to know what awk implementation it is and how the SIGPIPE signal ends-up being sent.

Comment: yep, using GNU awk would be better.  The answer above is just a simple hack compared to how GNU awk handles it.  and closing the file after each write will not be good for performance.  If Mike can install GNU awk, then that's exactly what he should do.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestions. But we don't have access to the system with SIGPIPE problem... We're content for the bypass by now. If there is the performance problem in the future, I will try to persuade them to update to gawk.

Comment: @Mike, what kind of system is it? (Just curious)

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas It should be the same as the env where the origin awk command works: uname -a Linux zed335a0 2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 26 13:37:13 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux awk -W version GNU Awk 3.1.7 Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2009 Free Software Foundation. Because they are two vm on a server and they should be the same as one is dev and one is test.  But I can't verify that as I don't have access to the test...

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in anything but `awk` would be silly IMO as it's a perfect match to `awk`'s abilities. You could do something like (`bash-4.3` syntax):

```
(unset fds; typeset -A fds
while IFS=';' read -r a b c rest; do
  file=/$a/$b
  [[ ${fds[$file]} ]] || exec {fds[$file]}> "$file"
  printf '%s\n' "$c" >&"${fds[$file]}"
done < file)
```

But that would be a lot less efficient (see also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](/q/169716)), and contrary to some `awk` implementations that can work around it, would make you run into the limit of number of concurrently opened file if there are too many files.

Alternatively, you could do (POSIX `sh` syntax):

```
while IFS=';' read -r a b c rest; do
  printf '%s\n' "$c" >> "/$a/$b"
done < file
```

But that would append the text to the files as opposed to overwrite them (and still be a lot less efficient than using `awk`).

You could also do it in `perl` but, there again, you'd need to do `awk`'s job of opening files and maintain the list of fds by hand:

```
perl -F ';' -lane '
  $file = "/$F[0]/$F[1]";
  unless (defined $fds{$file}) {
    open $fds{$file}, ">", $file or die "$file: $!\n";
  }
  print {$fds{$file}} $F[2]' < file
```

(with again the same potential problem with the limit on concurrently open files).

Comment: I know that awk is perfect for doing that. But when I do that with awk, I got the 141 exit code, SIGPIPE. I just want to bypasee this error...

Answer (score 0):

using cut:

```
while read -r line  ; do printf "in the file /%s/%s the content is %s\n" $(echo $line | cut -d';' -f1) $(echo $line | cut -d';' -f2) $(echo $line | cut -d';' -f3) ; done < file
```

And much shorter version (some stuff stolen from Stéphane Chazelas answer) and redirecting output to another file to save the results:

```
while IFS=';' read -r f1 f2 f3  ; do printf "in the file /%s/%s the content is %s\n" $f1 $f2 $f3 ; done < files > file2
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OP. It didn't ask for those lines as *printed output*. It asked that the result would be that the content of the files would be the values in the third field. Check what the original awk does.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes, fixed the answer.

Comment: Are you sure? Because it still seems to only print those sentences rather than create the files.

Comment: @RealSkeptic "How to print one column to other columns combined path without awk?" to me this means printing into the screen. But creating a file from output should be no issue.

Comment: Again, look at what the awk command in the OP does. It prints the value of the third field into a file whose name is composed of the first two fields. So if the value is "A;B;C", the file `/A/B` will now *actually* contain the value `C`. Thus, it is not printing the actual words "in the file..." - it is creating the files - several files, not one.